# Connect to a lot of databases simultaneously in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have found a lot of ways to change the default connection from the config/database.php file from all over the internet, but I don't want a multitenant app I need to connect to a lot of databases simultaneously and I lack the experience to get the code working. I have created so far model controller and table named DATABASES in my default database where I need to be connected all the time, where I store the configuration options from my application now I need to set up these connections and I can't do it.

I read all about this [on the fly database connection](https://lukevers.com/2015/03/25/on-the-fly-database-connections-with-laravel-5) and [multidatases connections](http://Hitting%20multiple%20databases%20dinamically%20with%20Laravel), but I can't figure out.

My logic is this:

1. Send configuration data options of the new database I in my table databases in my (default) Database.
2. Enable this database with a checkbox.
3. Show users from my default database and my new ENABLED connection.
4. Disable second or third connection but always have access to my default database.

I don't need code I need guidance, hope someone understand what I need to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Intro - 2 connections

Assuming you need 2 connections: **default** and **customized**, you'd provide their config in your `config/database.php` as usually, then you need:

```
>>> DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()
=> "default"

>>> DB::connection('custom')->getDatabaseName()
=> "customized"

// change the config...
>>> config(['database.connections.custom.database' => 'new_customized_db'])
=> null

// ...but once the connection is already open, config change doesn't affect it...
>>> DB::connection('custom')->getDatabaseName()
=> "customized"

// ...so we need to get rid of existing connection completely (reconnect() won't work)
>>> DB::purge('custom')
=> null

>>> DB::connection('custom')->getDatabaseName()
=> "new_customized_db"
```

---

### More connections

Above you can see what needs to be done. In your case, you can simply put **whole connection config** for each new connection you need, and it will work as expected:

```
>>> config(['database.connections.on_the_fly' => [
>>>    'database' => 'provided_on_the_fly',
>>>    ...
>>> ]])
=> null

>>> DB::connection('on_the_fly')->getDatabaseName()
=> "provided_on_the_fly"
```

---

### Eloquent

If you want to use custom connection for your **Eloquent models** you can use `SomeModel::on('on_the_fly')->find($id)` (fetched model **instance** will use the connection for all subsequent operations)

Comment: Thanks you Jarek im honored to get answer from you you Helped me a lot in different situations