# change Laravel default user db connection to another db connection

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have config/database.php as follow:

```
'default' => 'web',

'connections' => array(

# Our primary database connection
'web' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'host1',
    'database'  => 'database1',
    'username'  => 'user1',
    'password'  => 'pass1'
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),

# Our secondary database connection
'another' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'host2',
    'database'  => 'database2',
    'username'  => 'user2',
    'password'  => 'pass2'
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

),

and i'm using standard laravel 5.3 user authentication.

i tried in my registercontroller.php:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    $user = new user();
    $user->setConnection('another');
    ...
}
```

and still no luck

if i like to move or change the db connection into 'another' db connection for anything related with user (e.g. login, register, forgot pass, etc.), where is the settings that i need to change?

I just tried to change my config/database.php default connection as follow:

```
    'default' => 'another',
```

and it works, so it seems like i need to tell/configure somewhere that to use 'another' DB connection for any user transaction

Thanks!

Comment: [Check the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#introduction-database-considerations). Also, check the `/config/auth.php` file.

Comment: @TheAlpha Thanks for the comments, but it still didn't ring a bell to me... i can't see any sb connections settings there...

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001288/connect-to-a-lot-of-databases-simultaneously-in-laravel-5-2/39008750#39008750

Comment: Why are you using a different database connection for users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a different connection for specific models only, you can set a property in your Model class, e.g. App\User:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $connection = 'another';
 ...
}
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#basic-usage

Answer (score 0):

go to `app>auth.php`

and edit the table configuration:

```
 'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'your_table_here',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```